# cakephp-3.0 get table object from aliased Plugin Entity

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have an instance of an Entity and I need to get its table

I'm doing the following and it works fine most of the time:

```
$className =  $entity->source();
$entityTable = TableRegistry::get($className);
```

the problem arises with aliased Plugin entities: let's say I have a `Users` plugin and a `Group` model in it with this relationship

```
//plugins/Users/src/Model/Table/GroupsTable

$this->belongsTo('Parents', [
    'className' => 'Users.Groups',
    'foreignKey' => 'parent_id'
]);
```

now in a controller I'm doing something like:

```
$groupsTable = TableRegistry::get('Users.Groups');
$group = $groupsTable->get($some_id, ['contain' => 'Parents']);
$className =  $group->parent->source();
```

now `$className` contain `'Parents'` while I expect `'Users.Parents'`

how can I get the class name prefixed with the Plugin name? I tried `$this->belongsTo('Users.Parents', ...)` but it does not seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider this to be a possible bug, as it's unconsistent behavior, and having `Entity::source()` return anything other than the registry alias doesn't seem to be overly useful.

It happens in `\Cake\ORM\ResultSet::_groupResult()` where it uses the tables alias instead of its registry alias, and there doesn't seem to be anything you could do about it.

- **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.0.10/src/ORM/ResultSet.php#L511**
- **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.0.10/src/ORM/ResultSet.php#L550**

Please [**report this over at GitHub**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues).